# Replacing letters in string with their numeric position in the alphabet in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, indexing, methods, replace

I'm trying to make a method that, given a string, replaces every letter with its position in the alphabet.

If anything in the text isn't a letter, I want to ignore it and not return it.

```
"a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.
```

Example

```
alphabet_position("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
```

Should return `"20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"` (as a string)
I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
    def alphabet_position(text)
      alph = ("a".."z").to_a
      text = text.split(/./).map {|ch| if ch.in?(alph)
        ((alph.index[ch]).to_i+1).to_s
        else
          ""
        end
      }.join(" ").strip
    end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```rb
    def alphabet_position(text)
      text.downcase.split('').map do |letter|
        index = ('a'..'z').find_index(letter)
        index + 1 if index
      end.compact.join(' ')
    end
```

Comment: You probably want to build `('a'..'z')` outside of the loop so you don't create N ranges where N is equal to text.size.

Comment: i don't know that this is super important, but you don't need to do a linear scan of a range in order to get the offset of an character into the alphabet, because you can subtract ascii codes. not sure how to do that off the top of my head in ruby. also, on line 4, is zero truthy in ruby? there may be a bug for 'a'.

Answer (score 4):

First we can build the translation because Hash lookups are extremely fast:

```
# alternatively letter_to_number = ('a'..'z').each.with_index(1).to_h
letter_to_number = ('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h 
#=> {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5, "f"=>6, 
#    "g"=>7, "h"=>8, "i"=>9, "j"=>10, "k"=>11, "l"=>12, 
#    "m"=>13, "n"=>14, "o"=>15, "p"=>16, "q"=>17, "r"=>18, 
#    "s"=>19, "t"=>20, "u"=>21, "v"=>22, "w"=>23, "x"=>24, "y"=>25, "z"=>26}
```

Then simply swap them out

```
# ruby >= 2.7 
text.downcase.each_char.filter_map {|c| letter_to_number[c] }.join(' ')
# ruby < 2.7 
text.downcase.each_char.map {|c| letter_to_number[c] }.compact.join(' ')
#=> "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object('') do |c,s|
    n = c.ord
    if n.between?(97, 122)
      s << ' ' unless s.empty?
      s << (n-96).to_s
    end
  end
end
```

```
convert "Sunset was at twelve o'clock, somewhere, on some day"
  #=> "19 21 14 19 5 20 23 1 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11 19 15 13 5 23 8 5 18 5 15 14 19 15 13 5 4 1 25"
```

---

Lady and gentleman, start your engines!

```
def alphabet_position(text)
  text.downcase.split('').map do |letter|
    index = ('a'..'z').find_index(letter)
    index + 1 if index
  end.compact.join(' ')
end
```

```
def smnky_1_7(str)
  letter_to_number = ('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h
  str.downcase.each_char.filter_map {|c| letter_to_number[c] }.join(' ')
end
```

```
def smnky_pre_1_7(str)
  letter_to_number = ('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h
  str.downcase.each_char.map {|c| letter_to_number[c] }.compact.join(' ')
end
```

```
LETTER_TO_NUMBER = ('a'..'z').zip(1..26).to_h
def smnky_pre_w_constant(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.map {|c| LETTER_TO_NUMBER[c] }.compact.join(' ')
end
```

```
def convert_with_arr(str)
  str.downcase.each_char.with_object([]) do |c,arr|
    n = c.ord
    arr << n - 96 if n.between?(97, 122)
  end.join(' ')
end
```

```
str = "Sunset was at twelve o'clock, somewhere, on some day"
```

```
require 'benchmark'
```

```
def run(m, str)
  500.times { method(m).call(str) }
end
```

```
Benchmark.bm(19) do |x|
  x.report("Cary")                 { run(:convert, str) }
  x.report("Tatiana")              { run(:alphabet_position, str) }
  x.report("smnky 1.7")            { run(:smnky_1_7, str) }
  x.report("smnky pre 1.7")        { run(:smnky_1_7, str) }
  x.report("smnky pre w/constant") { run(:smnky_pre_w_constant, str) }
  x.report("Cary with arr")        { run(:convert_with_arr, str) }
end
```

```
                          user     system      total        real
Cary                  0.018610   0.000300   0.018910 (  0.019135)
Tatiana               0.067738   0.001138   0.068876 (  0.070317)
smnky 1.7             0.028659   0.001035   0.029694 (  0.030583)
smnky pre 1.7         0.032050   0.001662   0.033712 (  0.035089)
smnky pre w/constant  0.013705   0.000323   0.014028 (  0.014139)
Cary with arr         0.016989   0.000538   0.017527 (  0.017925)
```

Comment: Don't know if you've ever tried it but I find the `fruity` gem is better at benchmarking than the built in. Good call on the constant btw excepting that it gives an unfair advantage over `alphabet_position` which could implement the same.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I've used `fruity` quite a bit and will go back to it after my experience here. Initially I effectively had `1.times { method(m).call(str) }` and results from one run to the next were all over the map. Defining a constant seems fair as this kind of method would typically be called multiple times. I don't follow your comment about `alphabet_position`.

Comment: I simply meant, as I commented under the post, that the Range (`('a'..'z')`) could be constructed outside of the loop and in this case outside of the method itself (which is where the extra time savings comes in between `smnky_pre_1_7` and `smnky_pre_w_constant`). Also that is what I love about `fruity` since it is deterministic you don't have to concern yourself as much with the number of runs or the individual disparity between runs.

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, but `find_index` is still a linear search, no?

Comment: Absolutely it is and the savings would be minimal but savings none the less.

Comment: With fruity smnky_pre_2_7_w_constant is similar to cary_with_arr;      
cary_with_arr is similar to cary;      
cary is faster than smnky_pre_2_7 by 3x ± 1.0;       
smnky_pre_2_7 is faster than tatiana by 2x ± 1.0;      [Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/BlankOpaqueParser#main.rb) *repl.it is still using 2.5.1 so I had to remove the 2.7 option.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug a piece of code, run it line by line. Pretty soon you'll find that:

```rb
text = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
text.split(/./) #=> []
```

It does not do what you think it does.

I think you meant one of those:

```
text.split('') #=> ["T", "h", "e", " ", ...
text.chars #=> ["T", "h", "e", " ", ...
```

There are several more bugs but I'll leave those for you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer of @Siim Liiser, also you can use scan method to get letters.

```
text = "The sunset sets at twelve o' clock."
irb(main):002:0> text.scan(/[a-z]/)
=> ["h", "e", "s", "u", "n", "s", "e", "t", "s", "e", "t", "s", "a", "t", "t", "w", "e", "l", "v", "e", "o", "c", "l", "o", "c", "k"]
```

As you can see, the letter T is uppercase and are missing, to solve this youy can use downcase before to call the method scan:

```
irb(main):004:0> text.downcase.scan(/[a-z]/)
=> ["t", "h", "e", "s", "u", "n", "s", "e", "t", "s", "e", "t", "s", "a", "t", "t", "w", "e", "l", "v", "e", "o", "c", "l", "o", "c", "k"]
```